# Is there any cost to abusing custom tags and filters in Django

Tags: django

Is there any performance/architectural cost (or benefit) for defining too many custom tags and filters in Django? I'm still trying to wrap my mind around the fact that virtually any time Django template language doesn't allow me to do something I can fall back to define my own workaround.

I know this is a very generic question, but I'd be very grateful if you could give me some use cases when over-relying on these tools is either good or bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cost, but unless you overuse template tags you should not care.

This is why, by the way, Django widgets' html templates are defined in python code rather than in templates.

Remember that it doesn't matter how complicated is your template, in the end, if you use some caching mechanism the template is generated only once in a while..

Myself, I always prefer template tags and filters, even for the smallest things.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do functions rather than creating a custom tags. It is better to stick in the originally way because you don't know in the future if there are many improvements and other function would no longer be work.